# Django: External API response to be mapped and stored into complex model with manytomany relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django application where system on click of a button calls an API. API returns data in a complex structure consisting of a list of items with further nested jsons:

```
[ 
  {
    "_id": "76070ba8-e9f8-11ea-a1ac-42010a800002",
     "courses": [
      {
        "_id": "-machine-learning-solutions",
        "title": " Machine Learning Solutions",
        "tags": [
          "MAChine learning",
            ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "natural-language-processing",
        "title": "Natural Language Processing ",
        "tags": [
          "Natural Language"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "description": "MAchine Learning 
    "popularity": "This Program is not rated yet"
  },
{
similar structure
}]
```

I have a model consisting of many of many relationships with another model like:

```
class Bundle:
name = models.charField(max_length=100)
items = models.ManytoManyField(Item)
popularity = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Item:
name = models.charField(max_length=100)
provider = models.ForeignKey(provider,null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="+")
```

What is the best way to map the json converted response(I have converted it to json using json.dumps for rendering) to a model so that I can call a view on click on the screen and do modelObj.save() or create().

Is there a specific example or tutorial which helps us create a middleware kind of layer for easy mapping of responses? I explored serialiser but did not find a good way to save.

Note: due to many to many, I cannot iterate and save the bundles directly as it would throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your source code into the following one. Here I have created a `staticmethod` named as `map_and_save` which will support you to map and save the data based on the given `JSON` data format. You can call this method from your `view` class.

```
from django.db import models

class Bundle(models.Model):
    name = models.charField(max_length=100)
    items = models.ManytoManyField(Item)
    popularity = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def map_and_save(data=None):
        if data is None:
            return
        if isinstance(data, list):
            mapper = {"courses": ["items"], "description": "name", "popularity": "popularity"}
            for datum in data:
                bundle_data = {}
                item_instances = []
                for key, val in datum.items():
                    field_name = mapper.get(key, None)
                    if field_name is None:
                        continue
                    elif isinstance(field_name, list):
                        for _val in val:
                            item = Item.objects.create(name=_val.get("title"))
                            item_instances.append(item)
                        continue
                    bundle_data[field_name] = val
                bundle = Bundle.objects.create(**bundle_data)
                bundle.items.add(*item_instances)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.charField(max_length=100)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(provider,null=True, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
```

Comment: couple of questions:
1. why "courses": ["items"]? Would be better to create another mapper json for courses too?
2. Is it a good practice to call this from API app itself as bundle is another app and so is courses. Or should it be in bundle class where the model is defined?

Comment: @sudipgupta, 1. It works as a mapper to identify the `many-to-many` field easily for mapping purpose, since I have pointed it as a `list instance`. 2. There is no problem if you call it from anywhere in your app, but `import` the models properly before you call. It shouldn't have to be in the `Bundle` class.

Comment: got into a problem if anyone can answer here:
I converted the json to object using json.loads and sent to UI for rendering. The json is actually a list as seen above. On post of a form with hidden param = current item of the list, the object is posted back to the the view and is supposed to create model as guided by Sayem. However, the form data now has object with single quotes and cannot be dumped into a json again like json.dumps.
What is the suggested way?

Comment: To jsonify your data, use the following code.
`data = json.dumps(json.loads(str(data).replace("'", '"')))`

Comment: tried already. Thanks for the points. but it encoded the data. For now, will save and build a list as per your code and think about performance of saving every response later.
You are a savior mate!!